# Partition-key or no Partition-key for documentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In DocumentDb, how should I partition this?  Should I use partitionkey or not?  I don't think I can do "/address/state" since its collection... or can I?
Should I use "/Id" or "/name"?  is that even a good idea when those are mostly unique since id is Guid generated by documentDB and name is almost always unique.  So which one should I use?  I guess I may query by name but i thought partitionkey should be documents which can be grouped, by such as state, or city, or parentId.

Should I not use partitionKey at all?  And this applies to my AspNetuser schema user table in documentDb.  Which property should I use for that for the partitionKey?

```
public class Business
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description{ get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "addresses")]
    public List<Address> Addresses{ get; set; } 

   //more columns...
}


public class Address
{  
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "street")]
    public string Street{ get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "city")]
    public string City{ get; set; }  

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "state")]
    public string State{ get; set; }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use partitionkey or not?

In order to decide if you should partition your collection, here are some key points to consider:

***Single-partition collections***: have lower price options and the ability to execute queries and perform transactions across all collection data. They have the scalability and storage limits of a single partition (10GB and 10,000 RU/s). You do not have to specify a partition key for these collections. For scenarios that do not need large volumes of storage or throughput, single partition collections are a good fit.

***Partitioned collections***: can span multiple partitions and support very large amounts of storage and throughput. You must specify a partition key for these collection.

> I don't think I can do "/address/state" since its collection... or can I?

A [partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-partition-data#partition-keys) can be a property or path within your documents.

> Should I use "/Id" or "/name"? is that even a good idea when those are mostly unique since id is Guid generated by documentDB and name is almost always unique. So which one should I use?

An ideal partition key is one that appears frequently as a filter in your queries and has sufficient cardinality to ensure your solution is scalable. In “[Designing for partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#designing-for-partitioning)” section, you can find two key considerations for choosing a partition key and a few real-world scenarios, for detailed information, please check the link.

Comment: how will "/address/state"  work when business may have multiple addresses? won't it be like "/address[0]/state"?   MS support told me to use '/state' for the partition key collection if I don't embed the location but have it as a separate collection.  Smaller the grouping better it is.